# What are the default field types available when calling field_create_field?

Tags: api, drupal, documentation, field, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 module that creates a custom node type. It's working, but I need to add a field to the nodes to track how many times they get "used."

Where can I find the different field types I'm able to create when using [field_create_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7)? All I've [found reference to](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/examples/node_example/node_example.install?revision=1.11&view=markup&pathrev=HEAD) are "text" and "image." Is there an option for a "numeric" field type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by searching [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/) for [_field_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/_field_info). From there, I found [number_field_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--number--number.module/function/number_field_info/7), which includes a type of number_integer.

Comment: The fastest way is probably to look at the select box from which you choose which field type/widget to add when adding fields through the UI.

Comment: Isn't there a documentation page with the field types available ?
like this [page](http://groups.drupal.org/node/124289) but I'm not sure that's all right and what OP is looking for

Comment: actually I think all fields can be found here: [hook_field_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/implementations/hook_field_info/7)